How to create multicast on Kotlin/Native for ios/macos target
As the title says, in Swift, adding import Network can use NWMulticastGroup to create multicast, but Kotlin/Native for ios/macos still cannot use NWMulticastGroup after import platform.Network.* in src/appleMain. What is preventing me from using NWMulticastGroup? Or is this use case not currently supported? Thank you!
Other information:

kotlin: 2.0.0

gradle: 8.8

host: macOS 14.4.1

build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.multiplatform) // version "2.0.0"
}

kotlin {
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64(),

        macosArm64(),
        macosX64(),
    ).forEach { target ->
        target.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.coroutines)
        }
    }
}




NWMulticastGroup is written in Swift, and Kotlin cannot interoperate with Swift yet.
In other words, in Kotlin, you can only use the parts of Network.framework that are exposed to (Objective-)C. For example, instead of creating a NWMulticastGroup, you would need to call nw_group_descriptor_create_multicast. See the Objective-C version of the Network.framework documentation for more info. From a brief look, the APIs available to Kotlin mostly have a one-to-one correspondence with the Swift APIs - it's just that the former is a lot more "C-like".
I also found this post, which shows the Objective-C version of some Swift code using Network.framework. This may be helpful too.
